# Group of Unitaries: Strong Continuity

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the the Hilbert space of square integrable functions, shortly $\mathcal{L}^2$.

Consider the group of unitaries:
$$U:\mathbb{R}\to Aut(\mathcal{L}^2):(U_vf)(x):=f(x-v)$$

**Is there a "nice" way to show that it is strongly continuous:**
$$\|U_vf-f\|_2\to 0\text{ when }v\to 0\text{ for }f\in\mathcal{L}^2$$

Certainly, a good start is to reduce this to the dense subspace $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$ via:
$$\|U_v f+(-U_vf_0+U_vf_0-f_0+f_0)-f\|\leq \|f-f_0\|+\|U_vf_0-f_0\|+\|f_0-f\|$$
But then I argued quite technically that this indeed vanishes:
$$\|U_vf_0-f_0\|\to 0\text{ when }v\to 0\text{ for }f_0\in\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$$
Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Typically when considering dense subspaces (when we don't care about derivatives), we look at $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, not $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. There's no need to consider bump functions here since we do not care about analyticity at all and it's easier to work with compactly supported functions rather than those that simply die off at infinity. This is the way I would approach the problem.

Comment: I edited my comment but forgot to edit it entirely. I meant there's no reason to consider smooth functions since we don't care about the differential structure (for the purposes of our problem).

Comment: Yes I know I just didn't want to bother people about these minor issues (so for those who don't care about it) though I myself would even prefer simple functions $\mathcal{S}$ which perfectly fit for the problem and since being the heart of lebesgue integrability should be also dense if I'm not mistaken... but back to the problem how to prove strong continuity?

Comment: Simple functions work as well. In spirit, your solution/approach is correct. I don't think there's a better way to prove it. Analysis can be like that sometimes. Sometimes you just have to get your hands dirty with some really unfortunate computations/approximations.

Comment: Haha ^^ yes dirty hands before getting a clean kitchen.

Comment: Not quite duplicate since the missing step here is the left out in the answer there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like the Fourier transform and the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, then there's a trivial proof for $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. That should qualify as a "nice" way, but I think it's better to stick with basics using density arguments.

Comment: I like that proof it's really simple - I don't get it why people downvoted it. Anyway from me 1up ;)

Answer (score 1):

The remaining step that $\lVert U_v(f_0) - f_0\lVert_2 \to 0$ when $v \to 0$ holds for $f_0 \in C_c^{\infty}$ follows from two observations

1. $f_0$ is uniformly continuous because it has compact support
2. On a space $X$ with finite measure we have $\lVert f \rVert_2 \leq \mu(X)^{1/2} \lVert f \rVert_\infty$.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f_0$ is uniformly continuous, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|v| \lt \delta$ implies $\lVert U_v (f_0) - f_0 \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x \in\mathbb{R}} | f_0(x-v) - f_0(x)| \leq \varepsilon$.

We have shown so far that $|v| \lt \delta$ implies $\lVert U_v (f_0) - f_0 \rVert_\infty \leq \varepsilon$.

Suppose the support of $f_0$ is contained in $[-R,R]$. Then $|v| \leq 1$ implies that the support of $U_v(f_0)$ is contained in $[-R-1, R+1]$. Therefore $$\lVert U_v (f_0) - f_0 \rVert_2 \leq \sqrt{2R + 2} \lVert U_v (f_0) - f_0 \rVert_\infty \leq C\varepsilon$$
whenver $|y| \lt \min\{1,\delta\}$.

Comment: The argument works perfectly fine if the measure space is the real line $\mathbb{R}$. But what for the general case? There one needs to consider $supp f_0+B_\delta(0)$ which might fail to be contact again...

Comment: '-1' for missing argument (see previous comment)

Comment: @Freeze_S This downvote is ludicrous: What "missing argument" are you talking about? You only *asked* about the real line in your question and this answer fully addresses that... In any case: In your comment just replace $B_\delta(0)$ by the *closed* ball of radius $\delta$ and use that the sum of two compact sets is compact. You should really be able to make such simple modifications on your own.

Comment: Oh right i was only concerning the real line in my question - sorry about that. But over an infinite dimensional space why is the sum not union of two compacts again compact?

Comment: Ok I got it - thx for answering ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S So why is the downvote still there? I'm going to make a trivial edit in case you don't have enough privileges.

Comment: Yes I can only change if there has been made an edit... Changed it now.

Comment: @Freeze_S Wonderful. Also note that unless you ping users with "@username" they won't get pinged and won't notice it if you replied. I only saw it because I came here to check.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought always that if there has been made a comment on one of your questions or answers you'll get pinged...

Comment: @MattN.: Are you sure that users get pinged only by the "@"? I mean are you really sure about that? Btw thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Freeze_S Yes. The only exception that comes to mind now is when you post a comment on someone else's post like e.g. this answer. Then the author will get notified of the comments whether they include pings or not. No problem!